# MUI slider marks and label showing as equal spacing

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Im using mui slider with dynamic values,

```
for example const marks = [1, 3, 10].map((value) => ({
  value,
  label: value
}));

<Slider
          value={value != undefined ? parseInt(value) : 0}
          marks={marks}
          step={null}
          max={max?.value} // 10
          sx={CustomSliderStyles}
        />
```

after that my UI looks like [image]

But I expected equal spacing for 1, 3 and 10 like below

[image]

or Any other slider available for this feature?

Answer (score 0):

[image: slider with spacing]

```js
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  const marks = [
    { value: 0, label: 1 },
    { value: 1, label: 3 },
    { value: 2, label: 10 },
  ].map(({ value, label }) => ({
    value,
    label,
  }));

  const max = marks.reduce((prev, current) =>
    prev.value > current.value ? prev : current
  );

  return (
    <Slider
      value={value}
      onChange={(_, newValue: number) => {
        setValue(newValue);
      }}
      marks={marks}
      max={max?.value} // 10
    />
  );
};
```

You could do something like this where the values are evenly spaced and the labels are the labels you want. You just have to remember to reconvert the values to the correct labels if you are using it elsewhere